# iframe load event not being triggered in jquery

Tags: jquery, events, iframe

the load event is not being triggered after i download a pdf as attach to the iframe. any ideas?

```
jQuery.download = function(url, data, method, callback){
    var inputs = '';
    var iframeX;
    var downloadInterval;
    if(url && data){
        // remove old iframe if has
        if($("#iframeX")) $("#iframeX").remove();
        // creater new iframe
        iframeX= $('<iframe src="[removed]false" name="iframeX" id="iframeX"></iframe>').appendTo('body').hide();


            iframeX.load(function(){
                callback();
            });



        //split params into form inputs
        $.each(data, function(p, val){
            inputs+='<input type="hidden" name="'+ p +'" value="'+ val + '" />';
        });

        //create form to send request
        $('<form action="'+ url +'" method="'+ (method||'post') + '" target="iframeX">'+inputs+'</form>').appendTo('body').submit().remove();
    };
};
```

**MY ANSWER:**

so this is the best hack so far i got to fix this, it uses the fact that the popup "save as" window makes the main window out of focus.

```
var onBlur=function(){
    $('#spinner').html("");
}

    if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) { // check for Internet Explorer
        document.onfocusout = onBlur;
    } else {
        window.onblur = onBlur;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any PDF loading code in your example but my guess is that the PDF viewer running in the frame is no browser, so it doesn't support the standard HTML events.

Post another question asking what you need to *achieve*. Then we can maybe help.

[EDIT] What I mean: Where in all that is a HTML document loaded that could generate a HTML event? You put a PDF in the frame; PDFs don't generate HTML events.

But a solution might be to send two requests: First an AJAX request (runs in the background) and then `POST` the form. The server must keep the AJAX request pending until the PDF has been sent to the client and then, it should reply the AJAX request. That would give you an indication when the PDF has been transmitted. It's not perfect though.

Comment: no pdf viewer. im submitting the form and getting a content type=pdf in the response, which trigger the browser to open the "save as" box

Comment: What I mean: Where in all that is a HTML document loaded that could generate a HTML event? You put a PDF in the frame; PDFs don't generate HTML events.

Comment: yeah, i need synchronization between functions at server side for that through e.g. session vars which i dont want to do rite now. added a timer of 10s so in the worst case it will stop after that..